# Determining area of a region

Tags: geometry

Let $R$ be the set of all rectangles centered at the origin and with perimeter $1$(The center of a rectangle is the intersection of the diagonals).Let $S$ be a region that contains all of the rectangles in $R$(A region $A$ contains a region $B$ if $B$ is completely inside $A$).The minimum possible area of $S$ is $\pi a$.Find $a$.
I was able to come up with a solution using AM-GM and some contradictory stuffs.I am more interested to seeing a solution using calculus.

Comment: What value did you find for $a$?

Comment: If I understand your question: At the extreme the "worst case" "rectangle" is very close to a segment with length 1/2 - so S is a circle  with radius 1/4, and given the area of the circle, results a=1/16

Comment: Could you formally state the proof,please?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's examine an axis-aligned rectangle centered at origin, with perimeter $1$, and the vertex in the positive quadrant at $(x, y)$.  Because the perimeter of the rectangle is $1$,
$$p = 4 x + 4 y = 1, \quad x \ge 0, y \ge 0$$
we have
$$x + y = \frac{1}{4}, \quad x \ge 0, y \ge 0$$
i.e.
$$y = \frac{1}{4} - x$$

However, the rectangle could be oriented at any angle with respect to the axes, so what matters is the distance $r$ from the origin to the vertex:
$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{x^2 + \left(\frac{1}{4} - x\right)^2}$$
This distance is the same for all four vertices, of course.

$r$ reaches an extremum when its derivative is zero:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d r}{d x} & = 0 \\
~ & = \frac{2 x - 2 \left(\frac{1}{4} - x\right) }{ 2 \sqrt{x^2 + \left(\frac{1}{4} - x \right)^2}} \\
~ & = \frac{x - \left(\frac{1}{4} - x\right) }{ \sqrt{x^2 + \left(\frac{1}{4} - x \right)^2}} \\
~ & = \frac{2 x - \frac{1}{4} }{ \sqrt{x^2 + \left(\frac{1}{4} - x \right)^2}} \\
\end{aligned}$$
The equation is easier to manipulate, if we move some terms to the other side (essentially by adding them to both sides of the equation):
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{ 2 x }{ \sqrt{x^2 + \left(\frac{1}{4} - x \right)}} = 
\frac{ \frac{1}{4} }{ \sqrt{x^2 + \left(\frac{1}{4} - x \right)^2}} \\
\end{aligned}$$
and again because the square root term is positive for all $x$ we can multiply both sides by it, so we get
$$\begin{aligned}
2 x &= \frac{1}{4} \\
x &= \frac{1}{8} \\
\end{aligned}$$
and this $x$ yields the extremum $r$,
$$r = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{8}\right)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{32}}$$
Of course, we could also have observed that the line $y = \frac{1}{4} - x$ is closest to origin at $x = y = \frac{1}{8}$, so the minimum distance between that line and origin is $\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{32}}$.

However, we already know that at $x = \frac{1}{4}$, $y = 0$ (and of course $x = 0$, $y = \frac{1}{4}$) the distance from origin to the vertex is $r = \frac{1}{4}$, so we actually did "unnecessary" work above, as the extremum we found is the *minimum*, and the *maximum* is trivial, $r = \frac{1}{4}$.

Essentially, we proved that the vertices of rectangles centered at origin with perimeter $1$ have their vertices *outside* a circular disc centered at origin with radius $r = \sqrt{\frac{1}{32}} \approx 0.17678$; and *inside* a circular disc centered at origin with radius $r = \frac{1}{4} = 0.25$.

The question refers to the area $A = \pi a$ of area $S$ that contains *all* rectangles centered at origin with perimeter $1$.  Obviously, this is the larger circular disc with radius $r = \frac{1}{4}$, since this is the region that contains the vertices of all such rectangles.

Because the area of a circular disc with radius $r$ is $A = \pi r^2$, we have $a = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2$, i.e.
$$a = \frac{1}{16}$$